# Алгоритм генерации аватарок

Tags: веб-программирование, gravatar

День добрый!

Коллеги, подскажите алгоритм, по которому генерятся аватарки на данном сайте.

Спасибо.

Comment: Почитайте эту тему: [cкрипт генерации gravatar](http://hashcode.ru/questions/14940).

Answer (score 2):

На Питоне:

```
import urllib, hashlib

email = "me@and.you"
default = "http://hashcode.ru/wya.jpg"
size = 20

gravatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?" + urllib.urlencode({'gravatar_id':hashlib.md5(email.lower()).hexdigest(), 'default':default, 'size':str(size)})
```